# Property 'applicationNo' not found on type org.onnuri.cp.dto.BaptismApplicationDto

Tags: jsp, el, propertynotfoundexception

I want to display **user-defined class** with `jstl`
but I have problem with some error.

> Property 'applicationNo' not found on type
>   org.onnuri.cp.dto.BaptismApplicationDto

I add some code to fix.  <-- error code

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.ApplicationList}" var="list" >
<tr>
<td><c:out value="${baptismApplicationPK.applicationNo}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${status.current.applicationNo}" /></td>
<td></td>
<td><c:out value="${list.name}" /></td>  
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

BaptismApplicationDto.java

```
public class BaptismApplicationDto implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected BaptismApplicationPKDto baptismApplicationPK;
    private String name;

    public BaptismApplicationPKDto getBaptismApplicationPKDto() {
        return baptismApplicationPK;
    }
```

BaptismApplicationPKDto.java

```
public class BaptismApplicationPKDto implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int applicationNo;
    private int baptismTypeNo;
```

I solved the error.

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.ApplicationList}" var="list" >
<tr>
<td><c:out value="${baptismApplicationPKDto.applicationNo}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${status.current.applicationNo}" /></td>
<td></td>
<td><c:out value="${list.name}" /></td>  
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: The JSP EL is based on JavaBean conventions. So `${baptismApplicationPK.applicationNo}` looks for a `getApplicationNo()` getter. Do you have one in the class `BaptismApplicationDto`?

Comment: Thank you very much to JB NiZet!! I solved the problem. the wrong name is getBaptismApplicationPKDto() .